# Coins Collections like tiny wings

Tags: ios, collision-detection, box2d, collision

I am new to box2d. I want to create instance of sprites(Coins like tiny wings) and make it to collide with player.Is there a single sprite body definition is enough or i have to create a sprite body separately for all instance sprite
I need exact collision effect like tiny wings coins collection.Any help plz intimate me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I had to solve that problem I would create a class (for example Coin) then make multiple instances of it and storing them by using an array. Here is the code for creating a new coin and storing it in the array:

```
    //in the constructor function of the playing screen:
    coins = new Array();
    //the constructor function of the Coin should contain the startX and startY coordinate
    var newCoin= new Coin(100, 50);
    coins.push( newCoin );
    addChild( newCoin );
```

You can remove an element of an array using either exampleArray.pop ---> this will remove the last element
or exampleArray.splice(x,z) x is the element you remove, z is the number of elements you remove. exampleArray.splice(5,2) will remove 2 elements starting from the 5th. The first element of an array is numbered 0, the second is numbered 1 and so on...

You can check for collisions like this:

```
    for each (var coin in coins)
        {
            if (coin.hitTestObject(player))
            {
                 //do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for intimation will try it now